# "needs closed" and "needing closed"

Tags: grammaticality

"Needs closed", "needs resolved", "needs done"... I have never seen this before and it sounds totally incorrect, grammatically speaking. However, I have been hearing this so often, at work and even in written work documentation, that I am starting to doubt that I am right about this not being correct. Could anyone please help with that? Thank you.

Comment: That is prominent in the western half of Pennsylvania, but that dialectal usage stretches in a wide band from Western PA to Minnesota and Northern Missouri. It's widespread in the area between the Appalachian and Rocky Mountains in the northern half of the country.

Answer (score 1):

That's a colloquial usage in American English found primarily in the Mid-Western US. You are correct that it is not grammatically correct in standard English. You might hear something like this:

```
My car needs washed.
```

It should be:

```
My car needs to be washed.
My car needs washing.
I need to wash my car.
```

In informal speech, it's perfectly acceptable. But it is not appropriate for formal speech/writing. It's more dialectal, specifically, Mid-Western and North Midland American English. As far as your professional documents go, I suppose it is correct in that dialect, but a careful writer/speaker would not use that phrasing.

Comment: It's also found in Scotland.

Comment: @BarrieEngland That does not surprise me one bit and that may in fact be the source of that usage. That part of the US was populated by a large number of Scottish/Scots-Irish immigrants in the 18th and 19th centuries.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention work documentation as one source, I think these are just abbreviations where "to be" is dropped. Grammatically they don't pretend to be sentences by themselves, but if I saw "This needs done", I'd call that ungrammatical.